# How can I rewrite the terminal output of a program

Tags: sed, terminal, output

I'm running an application (CoronaSDK Simulator) from the terminal that puts an insanely long timestamp in front of every line of output.

Is there a way to use something like sed to chop it off and instead output everything else as it comes in (i.e. without having to wait until the program ends)?

I've tried a couple of things, but have had no luck so far...

Here are some sample lines:

```
2013-02-14 12:39:49.028 Corona Simulator[40803:707] |timer created
2013-02-14 12:39:49.029 Corona Simulator[40803:707] __in deck.lua__
2013-02-14 12:39:49.030 Corona Simulator[40803:707] storyboard.roomData.layout=A1 (room.lua)
```

Which I want to look like this:

```
|timer created
__in deck.lua__
storyboard.roomData.layout=A1 (room.lua)
```

I have tried

```
coronasim ./ | sed 's/Corona Simulator//'
```

as a test, and

```
coronasim ./ | sed -e 's/^.* //'
```

as suggested below, and even

```
coronasim ./ > /dev/null
```

but nothing seems to change the output.

The solutions was this:

```
coronasim ./ 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^.*] //'
```

as per choroba's suggestion below. Seems that the Corona SDK simulator sends output to stderr instead of stdout.

And for anyone else interested, created a simple bash script that runs the program in the current director in the simulator, stripping out the timestamps:

```
/Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Corona\ Simulat
or ./ 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^.*] //'
```

Comment: We can help if we see some sample output and what you have tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sed` as a *stream editor* should be the right tool for the job. Just redirect the output of your application to it:

```
myapp | sed -e 's/^.* //'
```

You might encounter problems, though:

1. If the application writes to a standard error rahter than standard output, you have to redirect the stream with

   myapp 2>&1 | sed -e ...
2. It is possible that the application would buffer its output if it is not connected to a terminal. Unless there is a specific option to change the behaviour, you are out of luck in this case.

Comment: Wrt. 2. I think you would be able to modify the behavior with `stdbuf`.